# Javascript - Return two decimal place value after multiplying a number

Tags: javascript, decimalformat

OK, I'm a novice at this but keen so help appreciated.

I have the following script that looks at field q13 which is a value and may or may not contain two decimal places. I then use the value returned and multiply by .8 to give 80% which I want to display in field q14. This works fine but decimal places can 1, 2, 3 etc. How do I ensure that I always return 2 decimal places? Rounding is not absolutely necessary.

```
function parseNumber(n) // Define a new function
{
    var f = parseFloat(n); // Convert to float number.
    return isNaN(f) ? 0 : f; // Treat invalid input as 0;
}

$("#Field13").on("change",function() {
    var x = parseNumber($("#q13 input").val());
    var y = x * 0.8;
    $("#q14 input").val(y);
});
```

Comment: thanks for edit Mike. Couldn't figure out what I was doing there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)** to specify number of digits to appear after the decimal point

```
$("#q14 input").val(y.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

use `toFixed` passing a number of decimals you want to have:

```
function parseNumber(n) // Define a new function
{
    var f = parseFloat(n); // Convert to float number.
    return isNaN(f) ? 0 : f; // Treat invalid input as 0;
}

$("#Field13").on("change",function() {
    var x = parseNumber($("#q13 input").val());
    var y = x * 0.8;
    $("#q14 input").val(y.toFixed(2));
});
```

Comment: sorry Pranav was 4 seconds faster

Comment: Thanks for speedy responses folks. Worked perfect. Thanks to all